# Datadroid and sliding menu / HoloEverwhere

Tags: android, slidingmenu, android-holo-everywhere, datadroid

I am trying to use Datadroid and sliding menu/HoloEverywhere. Sliding menu is using `Fragment`. Is it possible that Datadroid will be a Fragment to a main activity? :) I have successfully made a datadroid app in just one activity like this:

```
public final class tonesListActivity extends DataDroidActivity implements RequestListener,
OnClickListener, ConnectionErrorDialogListener, LoaderCallbacks {
.....
```

but how about if datadroid is a Fragment of an main activity? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

DataDroid - https://github.com/foxykeep/DataDroid?

DataDroidActivity extend android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.
Yea, you can add fragments to this activity, but it will be better if you change this line:
`java
public abstract class DataDroidActivity extends FragmentActivity`

on
`java
public abstract class DataDroidActivity extends org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity`

And made a similar transformation to DataDroidApplication.

Comment: Yes I tried your solution but It did not solve the problem because your solution as I understand is "tonesListActivity" can have a fragments but  my problem is that I have a main activity which has a sliding menu and "tonesListActivity" should be a fragment of the main activity. Any Ideas?